# Android web browser application stopping. Unable to start activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, runtimeexception

I'm trying to make a simple web browser for my android development class and every time I try to run the app I get the message "Unfortunately, Navegador has stopped".

I followed my teacher's code and everyone in my class could run it without problems. I'm starting to think the problem might be on my computer.

I'm using Eclipse. Some variables on the code are in spanish.

Here's my activity_main.xml
Basically it has 4 buttons

- Atras (Backward)
- Adelante (Forward)
- Actualizar (Refresh)
- Ir (Go to website)

  ```
  <Button 
   android:id="@+id/btAtras"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="top"
   android:layout_weight="3"
   android:text="Atras"
      />

  <Button 
   android:id="@+id/btAdelante"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="top"
   android:layout_weight="3"
   android:text="Adelante"
      />

  <Button 
   android:id="@+id/btActualizar"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_gravity="top"
   android:layout_weight="3"
   android:text="Actualizar"
      />
  ```

Here's my MainActivity.java

```
package com.curso.navegador;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


    EditText navegador;
    Button ir, atras, adelante, actualizar, borrar;
    WebView sitio;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        sitio = (WebView) findViewById (R.id.wvNavegador);
        sitio.setWebViewClient(new ViewClient());
        sitio.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        sitio.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        sitio.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        navegador = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.wvNavegador);
        ir =(Button) findViewById (R.id.btIr);
        atras =(Button) findViewById (R.id.btAtras);
        adelante =(Button) findViewById (R.id.btAdelante);
        actualizar = (Button) findViewById (R.id.btActualizar);

        ir.setOnClickListener(this);
        atras.setOnClickListener(this);
        adelante.setOnClickListener(this);
        actualizar.setOnClickListener(this);
        borrar.setOnClickListener(this);

        sitio.loadUrl("");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btIr:
            String web = navegador.getText().toString();
            sitio.loadUrl(web);
            break;
        case R.id.btAtras:
            if(sitio.canGoBack())
                sitio.goBack();
            break;
        case R.id.btAdelante:
            if(sitio.canGoForward())
                sitio.goForward();
            break;
        case R.id.btActualizar:
            sitio.reload();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

And we added this additional ViewClient.java class

```
package com.curso.navegador;

import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class ViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLading(WebView v, String url){
        v.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

In addition I added the permission on android manifest 
android.permission.INTERNET

```
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901): Process: com.curso.navegador, PID: 27901
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.curso.navegador/com.curso.navegador.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2426)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2490)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1354)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.webkit.WebView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at com.curso.navegador.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6245)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1130)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
03-11 12:07:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(27901):    ... 9 more
```

It's getting really frustrating because I'm getting this same type of error every time I start a new android application and this didn't happen before and I haven't found a solution yet.

I would appreciate very much your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stack trace is telling you what the problem is.  You are trying to cast a `WebView` to an `EditText`.  Based on what you have provided its this line

```
navegador = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.wvNavegador);
```

You are first casting `wvNavegador` to a webview few lines above and then to an edit text, which is obviously a problem.

Comment: I totally agree with @Naveed. Another thing to add as an advice. try to read and understand the log cat loggings/Errors you will learn and find out a lot. After you understand the error from the log cat, you can then do a simple research on the internet to find solutions.

Comment: Thanks!! I was so stressed out that I didn't even noticed that mistake.